# How to reduce CPU usage in a db-based multi threaded notification/email sender

Tags: c#, multithreading, windows-services, multitasking

I am trying to develop a windows service to send notifications to subscriptions.
The data is saved in a SQL server database.

Notifications are created by making a web POST request to a REST API endpoint and saved in a database table.

The service starts one Task that keeps reading notifications from this db table and add them to a queue.

Also the service starts few Tasks that keep reading from the queue and do the actual send process.

The code is working good and doing the job needed, but the problem is that CPU usage is 100% when running the service.

I tried to use Thread.Sleep or Task.Delay but neither helped me to reduce the CPU usage.

I have read in this codeprojct [page](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/175229/Threading-and-CPU-usage), that I need to use wait handlers and should wait on some condition. I could not have this working properly.

so can anyone advise what can I do to reduce CPU usage for `EnqueueTask` and `DequeueTask` ?

Here is the sender code:

```
static class NotificationSender
{
    static ConcurrentQueue<NotificationDelivery> deliveryQueue = null;
    static Task enqueueTask = null;
    static Task[] dequeueTasks = null;

    public static void StartSending(ServiceState serviceState)
    {
        PushService.InitServices();

        enqueueTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(EnqueueTask, serviceState);

        deliveryQueue = new ConcurrentQueue<NotificationDelivery>();

        int dequeueTasksCount = 10;
        dequeueTasks = new Task[dequeueTasksCount];
        for (int i = 0; i < dequeueTasksCount; i++)
        {
            dequeueTasks[i] = Task.Factory.StartNew(DequeueTask, serviceState);
        }
    }

    public static void EnqueueTask(object state)
    {
        ServiceState serviceState = (ServiceState)state;

        using (DSTeckWebPushNotificationsContext db = new DSTeckWebPushNotificationsContext())
        {
            while (!serviceState.CancellationTokenSource.Token.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                int toEnqueue = 100 - deliveryQueue.Count;

                if (toEnqueue > 0)
                {
                    // fetch some records from db to be enqueued
                    NotificationDelivery[] deliveries = db.NotificationDeliveries
                        .Include("Subscription")
                        .Include("Notification")
                        .Include("Notification.NotificationLanguages")
                        .Include("Notification.NotificationLanguages.Language")
                        .Where(nd => nd.Status == NotificationDeliveryStatus.Pending && DateTime.Now >= nd.StartSendingAt)
                        .OrderBy(nd => nd.StartSendingAt)
                        .Take(toEnqueue)
                        .ToArray();

                    foreach (NotificationDelivery delivery in deliveries)
                    {
                        delivery.Status = NotificationDeliveryStatus.Queued;
                        deliveryQueue.Enqueue(delivery);
                    }

                    if (deliveries.Length > 0)
                    {
                        db.SaveChanges(); // save Queued state, so not fetched again the next loop
                    }
                }

                // save any changes made by the DequeueTask
                // an event may be used here to know if any changes made
                db.SaveChanges();
            }

            Task.WaitAll(dequeueTasks);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }

    public async static void DequeueTask(object state)
    {
        ServiceState serviceState = (ServiceState)state;

        while (!serviceState.CancellationTokenSource.Token.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            NotificationDelivery delivery = null;

            if (deliveryQueue.TryDequeue(out delivery))
            {
                NotificationDeliveryStatus ns = NotificationDeliveryStatus.Pending;
                if (delivery.Subscription.Status == SubscriptionStatus.Subscribed)
                {
                    PushResult result = await PushService.DoPushAsync(delivery);

                    switch (result)
                    {
                        case PushResult.Pushed:
                            ns = NotificationDeliveryStatus.Delivered;
                            break;
                        case PushResult.Error:
                            ns = NotificationDeliveryStatus.FailureError;
                            break;
                        case PushResult.NotSupported:
                            ns = NotificationDeliveryStatus.FailureNotSupported;
                            break;
                        case PushResult.UnSubscribed:
                            ns = NotificationDeliveryStatus.FailureUnSubscribed;
                            delivery.Subscription.Status = SubscriptionStatus.UnSubscribed;
                            break;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    ns = NotificationDeliveryStatus.FailureUnSubscribed;
                }

                delivery.Status = ns;
                delivery.DeliveredAt = DateTime.Now;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void Wait()
    {
        Task.WaitAll(enqueueTask);
        Task.WaitAll(dequeueTasks);

        enqueueTask.Dispose();
        for(int i = 0; i < dequeueTasks.Length; i++)
        {
            dequeueTasks[i].Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

An object of type `ServiceState` is used to maintain starting and stopping the service, and here is the code for this type:

```
class ServiceState
{
    public CancellationTokenSource CancellationTokenSource { get; set; }

    public void Start()
    {
        CancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

        NotificationSender.StartSending(this);
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        CancellationTokenSource.Cancel();

        NotificationSender.Wait();
        CancellationTokenSource.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Here is the service start and stop code:

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    _serviceState = new ServiceState();
    _serviceState.Start();
}

protected override void OnStop()
{
    _serviceState.Stop();
}
```

Comment: Maybe use a concurrent queue and just deque from it? Now your code is just doing a busy loop and it will always use lots of CPU.

Comment: thanks for suggesting `ConcurrentQueue`, updated the sender code, but no changes on CPU usage.

Comment: i am not that familiar with windows services but the while loop seems like it will loop until service is stopped. So it will always run with 100% cpu even though there is nothing to dequeue. Maybe you can make it time triggered.

Comment: Did you remove the check for length and just use Deque? That will wait until there is an item available and no need to check for length or lock

Comment: Your `DequeueTask` and `EnqueueTask` methods run continously in a while loop in parallel and occupy the CPU completely. You should add wait/sleep in the while loops. You should also use the `CancellationToken` structure as an constructor argument and class field to the `NotificationSender` class, do not access the `CancellationTokenSource` directly from the `NotificationSender` object. When creating the tasks, use `TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning`.

Comment: many thanks, I used `TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning` when creating the tasks, also regarding the token, it is now passed as an argument to the sender class. you can see these changes on my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I could finally do good changes to maintain the CPU usage using wait handlers and a timer.

`EnqueueTask` will wait 5 seconds before trying to fetch data again from the notifications table if no notifications fetched. If no notifications fetched, it will start the timer and reset the wait handle. The timer elapsed callback will then set the wait handle.

Also `DequeueTask` is now using a wait handle. If no more items in the queue, it will reset the wait handle to stop dequeue-ing empty queue. `EnqueueTask` will set this wait handle when it adds items to the queue.

CPU usage is now <= 10%

And here is the updated `NotificationSender` code:

```
static class NotificationSender
{
    static ConcurrentQueue<NotificationDelivery> deliveryQueue = null;
    static Task enqueueTask = null;
    static Task[] dequeueTasks = null;

    static ManualResetEvent enqueueSignal = null;
    static ManualResetEvent dequeueSignal = null;

    static System.Timers.Timer enqueueTimer = null;

    public static void StartSending(CancellationToken token)
    {
        PushService.InitServices();

        using (DSTeckWebPushNotificationsContext db = new DSTeckWebPushNotificationsContext())
        {
            NotificationDelivery[] queuedDeliveries = db.NotificationDeliveries
                        .Where(nd => nd.Status == NotificationDeliveryStatus.Queued)
                        .ToArray();

            foreach (NotificationDelivery delivery in queuedDeliveries)
            {
                delivery.Status = NotificationDeliveryStatus.Pending;
            }

            db.SaveChanges();
        }

        enqueueSignal = new ManualResetEvent(true);
        dequeueSignal = new ManualResetEvent(false);

        enqueueTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        enqueueTimer.Elapsed += EnqueueTimerCallback;
        enqueueTimer.Interval = 5000;
        enqueueTimer.AutoReset = false;
        enqueueTimer.Stop();

        enqueueTask = new Task(EnqueueTask, token, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
        enqueueTask.Start();

        deliveryQueue = new ConcurrentQueue<NotificationDelivery>();

        int dequeueTasksCount = 10;
        dequeueTasks = new Task[dequeueTasksCount];
        for (int i = 0; i < dequeueTasksCount; i++)
        {
            dequeueTasks[i] = new Task(DequeueTask, token, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
            dequeueTasks[i].Start();
        }
    }

    public static void EnqueueTimerCallback(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        enqueueSignal.Set();
        enqueueTimer.Stop();
    }

    public static void EnqueueTask(object state)
    {
        CancellationToken token = (CancellationToken)state;

        using (DSTeckWebPushNotificationsContext db = new DSTeckWebPushNotificationsContext())
        {
            while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                if (enqueueSignal.WaitOne())
                {
                    int toEnqueue = 100 - deliveryQueue.Count;

                    if (toEnqueue > 0)
                    {
                        // fetch some records from db to be enqueued
                        NotificationDelivery[] deliveries = db.NotificationDeliveries
                            .Include("Subscription")
                            .Include("Notification")
                            .Include("Notification.NotificationLanguages")
                            .Include("Notification.NotificationLanguages.Language")
                            .Where(nd => nd.Status == NotificationDeliveryStatus.Pending && DateTime.Now >= nd.StartSendingAt)
                            .OrderBy(nd => nd.StartSendingAt)
                            .Take(toEnqueue)
                            .ToArray();

                        foreach (NotificationDelivery delivery in deliveries)
                        {
                            delivery.Status = NotificationDeliveryStatus.Queued;
                            deliveryQueue.Enqueue(delivery);
                        }

                        if (deliveries.Length > 0)
                        {
                            // save Queued state, so not fetched again the next loop
                            db.SaveChanges();

                            // signal the DequeueTask
                            dequeueSignal.Set();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            // no more notifications, wait 5 seconds before try fetching again
                            enqueueSignal.Reset();
                            enqueueTimer.Start();
                        }
                    }

                    // save any changes made by the DequeueTask
                    // an event may be used here to know if any changes made
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }
            }

            Task.WaitAll(dequeueTasks);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }

    public async static void DequeueTask(object state)
    {
        CancellationToken token = (CancellationToken)state;

        while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            if (dequeueSignal.WaitOne()) // block untill we have items in the queue
            {
                NotificationDelivery delivery = null;

                if (deliveryQueue.TryDequeue(out delivery))
                {
                    NotificationDeliveryStatus ns = NotificationDeliveryStatus.Pending;
                    if (delivery.Subscription.Status == SubscriptionStatus.Subscribed)
                    {
                        PushResult result = await PushService.DoPushAsync(delivery);

                        switch (result)
                        {
                            case PushResult.Pushed:
                                ns = NotificationDeliveryStatus.Delivered;
                                break;
                            case PushResult.Error:
                                ns = NotificationDeliveryStatus.FailureError;
                                break;
                            case PushResult.NotSupported:
                                ns = NotificationDeliveryStatus.FailureNotSupported;
                                break;
                            case PushResult.UnSubscribed:
                                ns = NotificationDeliveryStatus.FailureUnSubscribed;
                                delivery.Subscription.Status = SubscriptionStatus.UnSubscribed;
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ns = NotificationDeliveryStatus.FailureUnSubscribed;
                    }

                    delivery.Status = ns;
                    delivery.DeliveredAt = DateTime.Now;
                }
                else
                {
                    // empty queue, no more items
                    // stop dequeueing untill new items added by EnqueueTask
                    dequeueSignal.Reset();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void Wait()
    {
        Task.WaitAll(enqueueTask);
        Task.WaitAll(dequeueTasks);

        enqueueTask.Dispose();
        for(int i = 0; i < dequeueTasks.Length; i++)
        {
            dequeueTasks[i].Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: After Installed and started the service, it does nothing, seems it is not accessing the database and not sending.  I used a tool (ProcessExplorer) to investigate, i did not see any threads associted with my service. But when I edit `Program.cs` to manually call `OnStart` and run from visual studio, everything works well.

Comment: It seems the service was starting and stopping directly and there was nothing to wait for, so there was no time for tasks to run. I used to add `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite);` when running from visual studio.
But for the real service I solved it by adding `await Task.WhenAll(enqueueTask);` to the end of the `NotificationSender.StartSending` which kept the service running. I hope someone can find my post helpful.